# Displaying a grid of numbers in an iOS app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to determine the best way to display a grid of numbers in an iOS app. I have 100 numbers to display. So it will be 10 numbers in each row. These are not clickable. So just a read-only display. The only requirement is since I am showing a 10x10 grid on iOS it needs to be scrollable and zoomable. What is a good way to do approach this? I am new to iOS app development.

Comment: Use a UICollectionView.

Comment: I downloaded and looked at the example code from the Apple developer site and it feels like the UICollectionView wraps around the cells to fit the screen width. If so that is not what I want.

Comment: You can control that by the insets you set (which you would have to change on rotation), or you could write your own subclass of the flow layout that would ensure 10 items per line. If you don't want to use a collection view, then just put labels in a 10 x 10 matrix in a scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate views and add they into you scroll view:

```
const CGFloat total_items = 10;
const CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.bounds);
const CGFloat item_width = width / total_items;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < total_items; ++i) {
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < total_items; ++j) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(j*item_width, i*item_width, item_width, item_width)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 green:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 blue:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(i * total_items + j + 1)];
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
    }
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, item_width*total_items);
```

[image]